# Small gap between UINavigationBar and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I added a UISearch programmatically to my app and the UINavigation bar was added in interface builder. When I added the search bar it left a tiny gap between the search bar and the nav bar. Is there a way to merge them together? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,    self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

Answer (score 1):

If making sure that SearchBar is right under the navigation bar, I would use autolayout like so:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

id topLayoutGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchBar; //updated

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[searchBar]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(searchBar)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topLayoutGuide][searchBar]" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(searchBar, topLayoutGuide)]];
```

---

Edit:

I did some searching and found that it is not a gap. It is an image Apple uses to divide things into place. There are many options you can approach

1.) Search and destroy - find the UIImageView, and remove it from your bar.
[Remove UIToolbar hairline in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110883/remove-uitoolbar-hairline-in-ios-7)

2.) Set custom background for your bar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

Comment: Thanks. It's giving me an error at constraintsWithVisualFormat. It says searchBar is not a key in the views dictionary. I tried a few other things and I get the same error. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Try again with the extra line I added.

Comment: I tried the code with your changes. The code built but the view looked the same as the picture.

Comment: Any other suggestions Byte?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. I cannot reproduce your problem. I would need to see how you implement the whole thing, or at least the important part. I would not recommend a hack but you can also just set the yOffset to be -1 whereby it will close the gap. But again, beware of the hack, it could lead to unintentional consequences.