# Remove UIToolbar hairline in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

In iOS 7, Apple has changed `UIToolbar` to display a 1px hairline at its top. This is visually distracting in some cases, and there does not seem to be any public API to remove it.

Setting a shadowImage does not work.

I am looking for a way of removing the hairline in a relatively clean way, and keep the ordinary background blur.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you set youBar.clipsToBounds = YES, the hairline disappear.

Hope this help.

[EDIT]

For the navigationBar bottom hairline, the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180330/2011578 also works great.

Comment: Ah, good idea.
I also noticed, that the shadow image is below the nav-bar

Comment:   Combining with `.barStyle = -1` allows for a completely invisible toolbar (IAS HIG uncertain however)

Answer (score 5):

The hairline border is a UIImageView subview of the toolbar, you can hide it like this:

```
        for (UIView *subView in [self.toolbar subviews]) {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                // Hide the hairline border
                subView.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's always a bad idea to make assumptions about internal implementation details like this. Apple could change the implementation at any time.

Answer (score 5):

The line is it's shadowImage.
It can simply be removed by applying an empty UIImage.
**According to the documentation you also have to set a custom background image**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc ]init];
}
```

Be aware: Translucency won't work if you set own images in case you need that.

Comment: I think I should clarify my question then. I need to remove the hairline, but keep the blur (so no setting the background image).

Comment: This used to work in iOS 6, but in iOS 7, setting the shadow image to a transparent image will not work — there is a very faint, bright mark where the shadow is drawn.

Answer (score 4):

When using Storyboards,

```
self.clipsToBounds = true
```

can be setup for the Toolbar in the Runtime attributes. This will hide the hairline. 
Verified in iOS 7 and 8.

Answer (score 2):

It can be resolved easily on storyboard:

Select the View which is added as UIBarButtonItem Container & set its "Clip Subviews" & Run app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me... tried this for iOS 7

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not exactly what you want but surely this answer will help someone.**

If you want to change the bottom-border(shadow) color of UINavigationBar or UIToolbar instead of hiding it, you should set the background image and shadow image to your bar.

**For changing the the UINavigationBar's bottom-border(shadow)**

> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
>        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];

**For changing the the UIToolbar's bottom-border(shadow)**

> [yourToolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]
>   forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom
>   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
>
> [yourToolBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]
>   forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom];

Answer (score 1):

While somewhat hacky, subclassing `UITabBar` and overriding the `- (void)addSubview:` method, we can prevent the hairline separator from being added to the view hierarchy altogether:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.bounds.size.height < 2.0f) {
        return;
    }
    [super addSubview:view]; 
}
```

This way we'll get both the blurred tab bar and remove the hairline separator. It also ensures that `UITabBar` won't clip views to bounds, which is important for effects like large center buttons or other UI components.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this working via Storyboard in my case. I eventually used the appearance proxy to eliminate the shadow on all of my tool bars:

`[[UIToolbar appearance] setClipsToBounds:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

If you need hide hairline and show shadow clipsTobounds don't help

use:

```
TOOLBAR.subviews
      .filter { $0 is UIImageView }
      .forEach { $0.hidden = true }
```

or:

```
for case let imageView is UIImageView in TOOLBAR.subviews {
    imageView.hidden = true 
}
```